# getTypeId() returns configurable instead of simple for simple product - magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

[image: product 118 & 119 are associated to 117]I have one configurable product p1, and two simple product p2 and p3 which are associated to product p1.

when someone add to cart or buys p2, p3. I want to get parent product id instead of simple product id.

```
$product->getTypeId()
```

gives 'configurable' instead of 'simple' when someone adds / buys simple product associated with configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Configurable product Id of simple product that are associated to it by using this code

```
$simpleProductId = 282;  ($product->getId())

$parentIds =     Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
              ->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);

if(!empty($parentIds))
{
 $Parentproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
 echo $Parentproduct->getTypeId();  
}
```

Comment: $parentIds =     Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
              ->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);
 returns empty for me, when I try to get parent product of simple product

Comment: There may be two reason if you got empty array

1) Your simple product does not exists or wrong id of simple product.
2) There is no confiure product where this simple product is associated.

Can you please provide some more details.

Comment: I have updated question with screenshot. product 118 & 119 are associated to 117. when I try adding 118 to cart , I want to get parent product id instead of child product.

Comment: Hi, any idea why? Please let me know